# docker spring boot web services cannot connect to the docker mysql database

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated.
My docker spring boot web services cannot connect to my docker mysql database.
I can connect to my docker mysql database from toad.

This is the error:

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException:
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```
            version: "3.7"

        services:
          mysql:
             image: mysql:latest
             environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: Jadeite1!
            MYSQL_DATABASE: account
             ports:
            - "3306:3306"

             networks:
             - jadeite1000

          accountwebservices:
             image: bithead/accountwebservices:latest
             environment:
            SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/account
            SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: root
            SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: Jadeite1!
             mem_limit: 700m
             ports:
            - "8080:8080"
             networks:
             - jadeite1000

        networks:
          jadeite1000: null
```

This is my application.properties file:

```
    #Enabling MYSQL:
            spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/account
            spring.datasource.username=root
            spring.datasource.password=Jadeite1!
            spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

            server.port=8080
            #spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
            spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
            spring.jpa.show-sql=true
            spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
            rosalind_url=https://uguc.outsystemsenterprise.com/Rosalind/rest/v1/
            x_api_key=cc6c6117-ce9a-41a4-a2a0-34a992d27d5c
            x_fapi_financial_id=UHCE00VKVHPGEYRZB906
            spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false

            account.app.jwtSecret= bezKoderSecretKey
            account.app.jwtExpirationMs= 86400000
```

Comment: Are both containers in the same network?

Answer (score 2):

Your database and application runs in the separate container. So I recommend using the internal address and port instead of using external port and address for database connection.

```
SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/account
```